# Stuck on list of timezones arch linux

Tags: arch-linux

I typed in `timedatectl list-timezones` to list time zones. Now I just see the list of time zones and when I click a letter on my keyboard it just shows "log file:". How can I proceed from here?

Answer (score 3):

It's being pipe through "less". ~The man page will give you the details, but basically, you hit q to quit, or the spacebar to get another screenful.